# Assigning property through constructor overloading

Tags: c#, oop, constructor

In the following class, I want to assign `color` as `Color.White` for constructor 1; and when called through constructor 2, it should be assigned the parameter value. But in doing that, it first calls the constructor 1 which in turn first assigns `color` as `Color.White` and *then* the required value is assigned.

The problem becomes reasonable when many constructors are involved and objects are included.

Is there any way to deal with such unnecessary steps? I guess I'm missing something fundamental here.

```
public class Image
{
    Texture2D texture;
    Rectangle frame;
    Rectangle offsetBound;
    Color color;
    // Constructor 1
    public Image(Texture2D texture, Rectangle frame, Rectangle offsetBound)
    {
        this.texture = texture;
        this.frame = frame;
        this.offsetBound = offsetBound;
        this.color = Color.White;  // This is irrelevant
    }
    // Constructor 2
    public Image(Texture2D texture, Rectangle frame, Rectangle offsetBound, Color color)
        : this(texture, frame, offsetBound)
    {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not have ctor 1 call ctor 2 and pass white?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could rearrange things like this:

```
// Constructor 1
public Image(Texture2D texture, Rectangle frame, Rectangle offsetBound)
    : this(texture, frame, offsetBound, Color.White)
{ }

// Constructor 2
public Image(Texture2D texture, Rectangle frame, Rectangle offsetBound, Color color)        
{
    this.texture = texture;
    this.frame = frame;
    this.offsetBound = offsetBound;
    this.color = color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the next,eliminating the first constructor just leaving you with one constructor like so will provide the same outcome:

```
public Image(Texture2D texture, Rectangle frame, Rectangle offsetBound, Color? col = null)
{
    this.color = col ?? Color.White;
    this.texture = texture;
    this.frame = frame;
    this.offsetBound = offsetBound;
}
```

By using optional parameters you gain the same outcome as with your 2 ctors,if the user does not want to provide a color simply dont and it will be placed the default of Color.White.